# Should one wear a tallit to "set" a sefer Torah?

Tags: tallit-gadol, sefer-torah

Occasionally in my community, despite having daily minyanim et c., I have had to take out a sefer to have it set for the next kriah. I have worn a tallit when doing so. Is this practice typically followed in Ashkenazi schuls?

As always: CYLOR

Comment: I've never heard of doing that. What's the reason for your doing so?

Comment: I was told to do so, not by the LOR, but by someone who has grown up in Ashkenazi schuls.

Comment: What do you mean by "set"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, roll to the correct parshah